# Saving %CD% into variable, but path has spaces. How do I use my variable if the path has spaces?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Example:

```
set mydir=%CD%

echo %CD% 
C:\Stuff\More Stuff\Lots of Stuff
```

So how should the variable be used? Usually the entire path could be encased in quotes, but what about the variable?

```
for /f %G in (%mydir%\file.txt) DO (echo %G)
```

Comment: Try: `for /f %G in ("%mydir%\file.txt") do (echo %~G)`; in addition, change `set mydir=%CD%` to `set "mydir=%CD%"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is proper quotation. The following syntax is the only secure way to set a variable -- supposing the value does not contain quotation marks on its own, and the [command extensions are enabled](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) (which is the default anyway, and there are almost no situations where command extensions disturb):

```
set "myDir=%CD%"
```

The quotation marks do not become part of the value that way.

To use the value in a `for /F` loop as you try to do in your question, use this (remember to double the `%` signs in a batch file):

```
for /F "usebackq" %G in ("%myDir%\file.txt") do (echo %~G)
```

The [option `usebackq`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) is now required in order for the quoted path not to be treated as a literal string.

---

***EDIT: This is the former answer before I noticed the `/F` option at the `for` command.
I do not remove it because that might be helpful in case a standard `for` loop is used:***

<s>To use the value in a `for` loop as you try to do in your question, use this (remember to double the `%` signs in a batch file):</s>

```
for %G in ("%myDir%\file.txt") do (echo %~G)
```

The [`~` modifier](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) removes the quotation marks from the value.

To ensure that the expanded value is always surrounded by quotation marks, use this:

```
for %G in ("%myDir%\file.txt") do (echo "%~G")
```

In general, paths should always be quoted in order to avoid trouble with white-spaces and also other special characters. For example, `%myDir%` holds a path like `D:\Docs & Data`, the command line `echo D:\Docs & Data` echoes the string `D:\Docs`<kbd>SPACE</kbd> and tries to execute a command named `Data`, which does not exist (most probably), because the [`&` symbol](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) has a special meaning, namely to concatenate two separate commands in one line. Quoting the path like `echo "D:\Docs & Data"` avoids this problem (although the quotes are are returned too by `echo`; but they are ignored by commands that accept path arguments, like `cd` or `copy`, for instance).

Comment: This didn't work for me. Here is the output: **C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Batch**

The directory is : **C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Batch Testing**

Comment: The code in the question would read the file line by line as long as their are no spaces in the file name.  Putting quotes around it now treats it as a string unless you use the `usebackq` option to read the file.  So we need to know what the users intent is.

Comment: @NSV, by default the FOR command will use the space as a delimiter so it truncates the string it is processing.  You just need to add the delims option to the code so that it uses no delimiters. `for /f "delims=" %G in ("%myDir%\file.txt") do (echo "%~G")`

Comment: Argh, I did not notice the `/F` switch, so thanks, @Squashman! I think I have to rework my answer...

Comment: for /F "usebackq" %G in ("%myDir%\file.txt") do (echo %~G) Worked like a charm, except the "DO" command was displaying the parenthesis. I removed those and it worked great. Technically it wouldn't really matter with echo off, but it felt messy. 

Were there any reasons to keeping the () after the DO?

Comment: If there is a single command after `do` you do not need to use the parentheses; since you are trying all this directly in command prompt, you could use `... do @(echo "%~G")` or `... do @echo "%~G"` to avoid the command echoes of the part after `do`...

Answer (score 0):

Use either this:

```bat
set mydir="%CD%"

echo %mydir%
```

or in the loop case

```bat
set "mydir=%CD%"

echo "%mydir%"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("%mydir%\file.txt") DO echo %%G
```

although I would see no benefit in not using

```bat
echo "%__CD__%"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("%__CD__%file.txt") DO echo %%G
```

*Why set something you don't need?*

Comment: Not having luck with either.

Comment: As they both work in normal situations, then you should provide more code to substantiate your claim. _My guess is that you're trying to use it in a block without delayed expansion_.

Comment: Turns out delims=  wasn't needed.

Comment: Well, to be fair, as you are the only person who knew that only the first token of each line of `file.txt` was required we had to assume the position of greater robustness.